# insert wordpress shortcodes in raw php files

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm wondering if there is a possibility or technique of utilizing a wordpress plugin that provides capabilities based on implementing short codes in posts or pages.. wondering if I can use same short codes somehow in non-wordpress dashboard areas, such as `footer.php` and other raw `.php` files.

*Eg.* `[eyesonly level="administrator, editor, author"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the do_shortcode function.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode